# android bottom sheet in fragment not binding data to recycler view

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have a bottom sheet with recycler view and when it initializes the item list is empty and once in another fragment user select an item the adapter will be updated and notify change but it is not working and nothing happens

this is the class fragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ItemAdapter mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(new ArrayList<Items>());
    private ArrayList<Items> billList = new ArrayList<>();


//this is the onCreateView code
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

    View bottomSheet = root.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);

    mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    });

    mRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.rv_cached_order_item);
    mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(billList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    Button button = root.findViewById(R.id.btn_menu_order);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("TAG", "BottomSheetBehavior");
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    });
    initUser(root);
    return root;
}

// and this is where I notify the item change

    public void addToBill(Items item) {
        billList.add(item);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

//and the XML file looks like this it containes view page and on the view pager there is a recycler view which the user select an item and though the interface I update the bottom sheet recycler view adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Activity.ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu_tab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tabBackground="@color/app_background"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorAccent">


        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/menu_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/menu_tab" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="250dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_menu_order"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="@string/order"
            android:background="@color/app_background"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/menu_coordinatorLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/menu_pager"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_cached_order_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

making ItemAdapter static member function solved